# Laravel: How to rename reserved word column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

This would work if "read" was anything else except for "read":

```
Schema::table('messages', function($table)
{
    $table->renameColumn('read', 'opened');
});
```

Note: I am using "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*" in my composer.json and Laravel 4.2. So the problem is that Laravel complains:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read opened TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT
>   NULL' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE messages CHANGE read opened
>   TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL)

So somehow I need to "escape" the word "read", but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: [**`Read`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved keyword you can escape it using back-ticks `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double quotes (`""`) like this :

```
"read"
```

Or use back tick escaping as follows :

```
`read`
```

More information : [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html)